# Do I need the "Android unlocked dev phone" to test my android projects?

Tags: android

I bought an Android phone to use Flash. But to my surprise, Flash does not run on Android devices with arm v6. But I do want to make something useful and develop for it. Does it need to be "unlocked" for this purpose?

Comment: Yikes.  The various phone companies have implemented their own versions of flash specifically for their phones.  Flash will work with limited functionality under those implementations.  As far as I can discern it has been deemed a security risk to implement most of the functionality though.
If you want to develop for android your best bet is to bite the bullet and use Java with the Android SDK.
Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all, you can develop Android applications on any Android device.  Just make sure that if you want to make use of Google APIs that it's a device that supports those APIs.  Also, you'll need to enable development under Settings --> Development (I believe, the location actually varies depending on the version).

Comment: The setting you need to enable is Settings->Applications->Development->USB Debugging (make sure it is enabled).

Comment: Thanks, all was set and fiting like a glove

Answer (score 0):

Nope, just download the SDK and go. All current phones (that I know of) allow you to do debugging on-device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing using the Android SDK or NDK, any phone with Android Market is required to be able to be used as a developer device. If you are trying to develop IN Flash, then you will need a phone capable of Flash (Motorola Droid, any Snapdragon or better processor device) but on Android I don't believe there is a way to package a Flash app onto the device, and the Flash app is always run in the browser.

Comment: Yes, there is, but well, dont help me because of the necessary specs. Also I heard theres some slow time in using flash for this purpose.